# Perl: Strange behavior of chomp

Tags: perl

`chomp` function in Perl removes the record separator character (s) from a variable that appears at the end. However, in the following code, it remove more than that - it remove some characters from the front of the variable as well. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use String::Util qw(trim);
use feature 'say';

{
open FILE, "conf.txt" or die "Can't open file";
local $/ = ';';
my %hash;
my @val;

while (<FILE>){
    next if (/^\s+$/);
    @val=split /=/;
    $hash{$val[0]}=$val[1];
}

say $hash{"name1"};
say chomp $hash{"name1"};
close FILE;
}
```

The `conf.txt` file looks like so:

```
name1=va
l1;
name2=v
a
l2;
name3=val3;
name4=val4;
```

The output of the code is like so:

```
~ $ ./readconf.pl 
va
l1;
1
```

I was expecting that the output of `say chomp $hash{"name1"};` would be `va\nl1`. Why does it just output `1`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#chomp):

> It returns the total number of characters removed from all its arguments.

`chomp` modifies its argument in place. It doesn't return the possibly truncated string.